# Morphia MongoDB Null Object

Tags: java, mongodb, morphia

I have two simple POJO's Company and Employee. I am using morphia to save them in MongoDB. Employee is a referenced document in Company class. I am successfully able to save the Company Object but when i try to retrieve . I get a **null** object

**Company.java**

```
package com.hifi.model;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

import org.bson.types.ObjectId;
import org.mongodb.morphia.annotations.Entity;
import org.mongodb.morphia.annotations.Id;
import org.mongodb.morphia.annotations.Reference;

@XmlRootElement
@Entity("companies")
public class Company {

private String companyName;
private String numberOfEmployees;
@Id
private ObjectId companyId;
@Reference
private Employee emp;
public ObjectId getCompanyId() {
    return companyId;
}
public void setCompanyId(ObjectId companyId) {
    this.companyId = companyId;
}

public String getCompanyName() {
    return companyName;
}
public void setCompanyName(String companyName) {
    this.companyName = companyName;
}
public String getNumberOfEmployees() {
    return numberOfEmployees;
}
public void setNumberOfEmployees(String numberOfEmployees) {
    this.numberOfEmployees = numberOfEmployees;
}
public Employee getEmp() {
    return emp;
}
public void setEmp(Employee emp) {
    this.emp = emp;
}

}
```

**Employee.java**

```
package com.hifi.model;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

import org.bson.types.ObjectId;
import org.mongodb.morphia.annotations.Entity;
import org.mongodb.morphia.annotations.Id;

@XmlRootElement
@Entity("employees")
public class Employee {

private String name;
private int age;
@Id
private ObjectId empId;
public ObjectId getEmpId() {
    return empId;
}
public void setEmpId(ObjectId empId) {
    this.empId = empId;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public int getAge() {
    return age;
}
public void setAge(int age) {
    this.age = age;
}

}
```

**Here is my morphia Query example**

```
package com.hifi;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.mongodb.morphia.Datastore;
import org.mongodb.morphia.Morphia;
import org.mongodb.morphia.query.Query;

import com.hifi.database.MongoDBSingleton;
import com.hifi.model.Company;
import com.hifi.model.Employee;
import com.hifi.util.Constants;
import com.mongodb.MongoClient;

public class MorphiaQuery {

MongoDBSingleton mongoInstance;
private Datastore datastore;
private Morphia morphia;

private List<Company> friendsPostList = new ArrayList<Company>();

public List<Company> query() {

    morphia = new Morphia();

    morphia.mapPackage("com.hifi.model");
    // create the Datastore connecting to the default port on the local
    // host
    datastore = morphia.createDatastore(new MongoClient(), 
    Constants.MONGO_DB);
    // datastore.ensureIndexes();
    // mongoInstance = MongoDBSingleton.getInstance();// Get the 
    mongoDb
    // connection
    // datastore = mongoInstance.getDataStore();

    Query<Company> query = datastore.createQuery(Company.class);

    Query<Employee> userQuery = datastore.createQuery(Employee.class);

    userQuery.field("age").equal(12);

    Employee emp = userQuery.get();
    System.out.println("Printing -------user " + emp);
    query.criteria("emp").equal(emp);
    // query.order("-postTimeStamp"); // Order by timestamp DESC
    // query.limit(1);
    friendsPostList = query.asList();

    return friendsPostList;

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    MorphiaQuery m = new MorphiaQuery();
    System.out.println(m.query());

}

}
```

**Console Output:**strong text****

```
Apr 09, 2017 12:30:06 PM 
org.mongodb.morphia.logging.MorphiaLoggerFactory chooseLoggerFactory

INFO: LoggerImplFactory set to 
org.mongodb.morphia.logging.jdk.JDKLoggerFactory

Apr 09, 2017 12:30:08 PM com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.JULLogger log
INFO: Cluster created with settings {hosts=[127.0.0.1:27017], 
mode=SINGLE, requiredClusterType=UNKNOWN, serverSelectionTimeout='30000 
ms', maxWaitQueueSize=500}

Apr 09, 2017 12:30:08 PM com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.JULLogger log
INFO: Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:1, serverValue:26}] to 
127.0.0.1:27017

Apr 09, 2017 12:30:08 PM com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.JULLogger log
INFO: Monitor thread successfully connected to server with description 
ServerDescription{address=127.0.0.1:27017, type=STANDALONE, 
state=CONNECTED, ok=true, version=ServerVersion{versionList=[3, 4, 2]}, 
minWireVersion=0, maxWireVersion=5, maxDocumentSize=16777216, 
roundTripTimeNanos=970170}

Apr 09, 2017 12:30:09 PM com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.JULLogger log
INFO: Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:2, serverValue:27}] to 
127.0.0.1:27017
Printing -------user null
[]
```

**My JUnit TEST CASE**

```
    @Test
    public void testCreateCompany() {
    PostClient postClient = new PostClient();

    Company company = new Company();
    company.setCompanyName("ABC");
    company.setCompanyId(new ObjectId());
    company.setNumberOfEmployees("100");

    Employee user = new Employee();
    user.setName("siva");
    user.setAge(12);
    user.setEmpId(new ObjectId());
    company.setEmp(user);

    company = postClient.create(company);
    assertNotNull(company);

   }
```

It was working fine until yesterday. Btw iam using morphia 1.3.1 maven dependancy. Kindly help!!!

Answer (score 0):

You are saving a Company object in your unit test, but you forget about the Employee.

The `@Reference` annotated `emp` field in the Company class tells Morphia to only save a reference to the Employee, it doesn't also store the employee as part of the insertion.

Comment: Are you sure on this? Coz i think mongodb implicitly creates the user docuement for you . But i will try this surely!!!

Comment: @PratikKulkarni Yes, definitely. I've tried it myself. Good luck!